# Stored procedure Parameter Type validation

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

net code that executes a stored procedure

```
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("get_list_of_users", connection)
        Dim table As New DataTable
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim param As New SqlParameter("@TypeID", SqlDbType.Int)

        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        param.Value = typeID
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param)

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
        adapter.Fill(table)
```

Unfortunately the *@TypeID* parameter in the stored procedure was not configured to be an *integer* but a *bit*, you can imagine the consequences and the amount of time we had to waste debugging it.

Is there a way to configure a "stricter" mode to pass parameters to a stored procedure so that an exception would be raised if the data type defined does not match the stored proc definition?

Thanks all

Comment: No. This is very fundamental in that even T-SQL can't validate this -- the actual types of stored procedure arguments simply aren't known in the call, and SQL Server will take care of implicit conversion for you. Only if this conversion fails will you get an error -- and as you've noticed, T-SQL conversions are ridiculously lossy.

Comment: Where are you wanting to check it? Within SQL or in your C# application? The errors are usually pretty descriptive.

Comment: @Leonidas199x: you'll find that SQL Server has no problem implicitly converting the integer `42` to the `BIT` value `1`, without any error. But it's almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: I know, but you could check its type in C# before it is passed to the stored proc.

Comment: @Leonidas199x: unfortunately, if the C# type and value are correct and the stored procedure parameter type is wrong, there's not much you can do on the C# end. Unless you feel like querying `sys.parameters` before every call to detect mismatches, that is.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - you are spot on - I would love to have an exception where such implicit conversion happens.

Comment: I see, apologies, didn't read that properly, my bad. The only way I see to check this is to put in a load of conversions to ensure what you are putting in is the same when it is passed to the stored proc which will never be great for overhead. OP - Out of interest, what was causing you issues debugging? Did you hook up the SP to VS to carry on debugging through there?

Comment: @abx78: You and me both, but it's not going to happen. The best approach is the one David illustrates: write code to generate sproc calls from the parameters, so no mismatch is possible, or use an ORM to generate such mappings for you. If your client code matches your stored procedure, at least detecting type mismatches there works. SQL Server will not help you, it already thinks it's being helpful by converting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not saying this is good, but, if you really want to check, you could do it in the stored proc. 
Below is a quick example that may give you a few things you could implement if you wanted. In C# convert the int to string, and pass it in as a parameter also, then it is converted back, to make sure the two match. In the below, I have added the BIT as you had, so the error is raised.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.pTypeTest

    @int BIT            ,
    @str NVARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @bitTheSame     BIT             ,
            @intBaseType    NVARCHAR(20)    ,   
            @strBaseType    NVARCHAR(20);

    SELECT @intBaseType = CAST(SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@int,'BaseType') AS NVARCHAR(20));
    SELECT @strBaseType = CAST(SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@str,'BaseType') AS NVARCHAR(20));

    SELECT @bitTheSame = CASE WHEN CAST(@int AS NVARCHAR(10)) <> @str THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;

    IF(@bitTheSame = 0)
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @message NVARCHAR(200);
            SELECT @message = 'Something went wrong, @str: ' + @str + ' does not match @int: '+CAST(@int AS NVARCHAR(10))+' when it has been converted. @str is a '+@strBaseType+' and @int is a '+@intBaseType;
            RAISERROR(@message,16,1);
        END
    IF(@bitTheSame = 1)
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Ok';
        END

END
```

Example:

```
EXEC dbo.pTypeTest @int = 1000,@str = '1000';
```

Raised error:

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure pTypeTest, Line 24 Something
>   went wrong, @str: 1000 does not match @int: 1 when it has been
>   converted. @str is a nvarchar and @int is a bit

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly legal to call a procedure with parameter values that have implicit conversions to the parameter types.

But you can (and should) move away from hand writing the stored procedure calls.  Instead generate the code based on the SQL Server metadata, using, for instance, a T4 template.

EG a query to give you the procedures and parameter types would look like this:

```
select object_name(m.object_id) ObjectName, 
       SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) SchemaName,
       o.type_desc ObjectTypeDesc,
       p.name ParameterName,
       t.name TypeName,
       p.precision,
       p.scale,
       p.max_length,
       p.default_value,
       p.is_output     
from 
sys.sql_modules m
join sys.objects o
  on o.object_id = m.object_id
join sys.parameters p
  on m.object_id = p.object_id
join sys.types t
  on p.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
order by o.object_id, p.parameter_id
```